# Regular expression for validating variable assignment

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that will validate a variable assignments in a BB style code that I'm currently developing.

Variable assignments look like this

```
[assign {var_name} = "string value"]
```

You can assign to multiple variables like

```
[assign {var1} = {var2} = true]
```

Or add to a variable with

```
[assign {var_name} .= " more..."]
```

Increment/decrement variables

```
[assign {var}++] or [assign {var}--]
```

Assign a negated value

```
[assign {var1} = !{var2}]
```

So far I've come up with the following regex with doesn't work very well

```
     /
       \[assign
         (?:
           [\s]*(?:
             [\!]?\{[^\}]+\}(?:(?:\+\+)|(?:\-\-))?
             |
             [0-9]+
             |
             \"[^\"]+\"
             |
             \'[^\']+\'
             |
             true
             |
             false
           )[\s]*(?:\=[\s]*|\.\=[\s]*)?
         )+
       \]
     /
```

I'm stuck with the following:

- I need to ensure that .= or = is used between each part
- And ensure that values and variables are assigned to variables, but not variables assigned to values
- Finally ensure there is an actual assignment unless the value is incremented or decremented

Update:
working regex

```
       \[assign(?:\s)* 
         (
           \{[^\}]+\}
           (?:
             \+\+
             |
             --
             |
             (?:\s)*(?:\.)?=(?:\s)*
             (?:(?:!)?\{[^\}]+\}(?:\s)*(?:\.)?=(?:\s)*)*
             (?:
               [0-9]+
               |
               "[^"]+"
               |
               '[^']+'
               |
               true
               |
               false
               |
               (?:!)?\{[^\}]+\}
             )
           )
         )
       (?:\s)*\]
```

Comment: I'm sure some one is going to say it, but let me be the first.  This is a task better suited to a parser and a lexer.

Comment: I'm going to be converting this to php, but it's not a template language before anyone jumps on that one. It is a language available to end users. The functionality is very limited which allows me to essentially validate code before converting and being parsed by php. The validation is a requirement as it shouldn't be possible for a user to "break" things with bad code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to match those cases, you could use [the following regular expression](http://regexr.com?2v0du) to parse them:

```
^(?:assign {var.*?})(\+\+|--| (?:\.)?= ({var.*?} = )*(true|".+"|!{var.*?}))$
```

#### It will match the following:

```
assign {var_name} = "string value"
assign {var1} = {var2} = true
assign {var_name} .= " more..."
assign {var}++
assign {var}--
assign {var1} = !{var2}
assign {var235} = "two"
assign {var1} = {var2} = {var3} = true
```

#### And it will not match the following:

```
assign lol = hi
assign {var3} = {var4}
assign {var5} = !"hi"
```

Comment: The number of assignments is not limited plus your regex would allow far too much through.

Comment: This regex will allow for any number of assignments. What does it allow that shouldn't be? I just used all of your examples, and a few of my own added on.

Comment: Sorry wasn't really awake when I first looked at this. It does basically do what I need. I've updated my question with my working regex for everything.